# What's a good working strategy to read and write data on the Todoist web service from a Windows pc without admin priviliges?

Tags: python, pyscript, todoist

Situation: I am a non-programmer with almost zero coding experience.
I want to run custom python scripts on my task list on the Todoist website to improve the functionality. Namely: copying tasks and subtasks more easily.
I have a work pc running Windows 10, but I cannot install or run any unknown software on this.

So I am mainly looking for advice on what the best strategy to pursue is here. I can try to find out all the nitty gritty details myself if someone sets me on the right path.

The main ideas I have right now after some googling:

1. Run the code from some web service and access it through a browser. (don't know if possible or even what to look for)
2. Use a html file containing py-script. (i have gotten py-script to run, but I have no idea how I would get the Todoist API to work)

I am currently not worried about the actual coding of the functions i want. I don't need help with this right now. I will try and figure this out myself as I think it is a good beginner coding exercice.

Is this at all possible or is this a dead end/too complex? Please let me know if my question is too vague so I can clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you write and execute your own code you won't have any privilege issues. For your specific requirements javaScript should be better?

Answer (score 0):

You would not need admin privileges for the things you have mentioned,

if you want to run code online I would recommend replit.com which supports most languages.

However, from somebody who learned programming themselfs,  I recommend as a beginner starting with smaller projects as learning as you go is not an effective stratagy.